# AWS Custom Authorizer - Get token from cookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently building a web application whose backend is purely build in API Gateway/Lambda. I build a custom JSON Web Token (JWT) authorizer to authorize the users. At the moment I'm passing token in header field.

Unfortunately, I'm only able to define a header field in which the token is send to API Gateway.My applications stores the token in a cookie.

Is there any option to access the cookie directly so that it can authenticate using lambda.

For example:

Now I'm passing:-

`method.request.header.Authorizer`

But I need somehting like this :-

`methods.request.header.Cookie`

Any workaround ? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now you should be able to access all the headers including Cookie header, using [Custom Authorizers of the REQUEST type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html). Recently AWS introduced this feature to allow access to more than Token Header.

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks man. Is there any example or how should I setup this.

Comment: @Sanket Its the same approach as using Custom Authorizer previously, After selecting the request type Lambda function will receive the other headers you define here. Thats the main difference.

Comment: yes I did the same steps but surprisingly it's not passing the header value whose key is "Cookie". But when I pass it as "Authorization", it works like perfectly. Check this screenshot (http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1507896408.png) I'm doing something wrong ?